# Listview click not working everytime in android

Tags: java, android, listview

i created a db and stores values in and displayed it in listview... when i click the values i can edit it.. but when i add two values,  if the 1st value get deleted no problem.. when i click the second value app stops working...

my listview code...

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

    ListView obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayContact.class);

            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your logcat here

Comment: add your logcat please

Comment: `int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;` - You seem to be basing your item selection on its position in the `ListView`. That's probably not going to sync up with its ID in the db, after adding/deleting items, if that's indeed how you're trying to handle this. However, you've not provide enough info for us to be certain, or to recommend a specific solution.

Comment: Most probably after you are deleting your values from the listview you are not updating your arraylist properly again and calling notifydatasetchanged on the adapter

Comment: Your listview and database is not properly sync. After adding/editing/deleting you should update your listview.

Comment: How can i solve this.?

Comment: You could use a custom view (instead of a plain String) that stores the id of the contact. Also you probably should update the adapter with the new arraylist corresponding to the new state of the contacts list. And, post your logcat please :)